# Log4cxx, what purpose does it serve?

Tags: c++, log4cxx

I've seen Log4cxx a bit and am confused as to what it's purpose actually is.

Originally when I saw Logger I assumed it was a key to access a system (that without it you couldn't get the information that you needed). Though looking more at it, it seems to be more of a tracking system? But a tracking system for what and what would one use as a "logger" then?

I'm sorry if this question is vague, but hence my  not understanding it `:p`

I have found this: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Log4cxx.html but no one seems to give a *why* you use it and how it's beneficial. Can anyone give me an example? I think that's the biggest piece I'm missing.

Comment: It's an application logging library. You know how you would do things like print statements about what your application is doing at any given time, for debugging or informational purposes? That's what `log4cxx` can do, and can help you consolidate that and print to a file and to `stdout` at the same time, among other things. If that's still too abstract for you, read this page about [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html), which talks about some real use cases for a similar library that's written for Java.

Comment: @birryree ah I see, thanks, and thanks for the link :) Fvu, not sure why you would want to delete the question, I was only asking for clarification.

Comment: It does not provide a good example however, imo. And since when has an "enthusiast" been classified as an expert? I've been programming for a little less than two years and have never come across it before. Also, there are plenty of questions similar to mine on this site asking for clarification or examples of a certain topic that text book type answers do not provide better. If the mods want to close it than they can, but far bid for you to make people feel like they can't ask questions for better understanding of things they should "know". If you don't like a question, don't answer it.

Comment: @fvu I'd rather see a request for migration to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) than the stigmatizing remarks.

Comment: @fvu the moderators haven't dumped the "low quality" question, so I'm not sure why they'd dump the corresponding remarks. It's enough to criticize the nature of the question, but not the OP's inexperience. That's all. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A logger is not an authentification system. It logs (collects and saves) information, potentially in a logfile. See [wikipedia for logging.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logfile)